# Unable to install gems in ruby 1.8.7-p374

Tags: rubygems, ruby-1.8.7

I am using
ruby-1.8.7-p374,
rubygems - 1.8.29 and
rvm - 1.29.3

When I try to install any gem for example bundler, I get the following error

> While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
>    Marshal.load reentered at marshal_load

Comment: What OS are you using? I'm having the same error on fedora 27.

Comment: @Qwertie I am using Solus 3.26.2

Answer (score 1):

Try running `gem update --system`. Worked for me on fedora 27 using rvm.

**Update:** It is now likely impossible to install gems using this ruby version due to rubygems disabling TLS 1.0 and 1.1 https://blog.rubygems.org/2018/02/24/tls-10-and-11-deprecation-notice.html

Comment: @AnushaBhat See my update, you will have to update ruby.

Answer (score 0):

you should not be using Ruby 1.8 -- it is End Of Life since 2014.
That means no more security updates.

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/07/01/eol-for-1-8-7-and-1-9-2/

You should upgrade to 2.3, 2.4 or 2.5